# IOS app not receiving notification if close

Tags: flutter

Good Day.
Im using firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3 in my app. Everything is working fine in android but on ios Im only receiving the notification when the app is open. If the app is close Im not receiving notification. Have you encounter the same issue? Please let me know if you have some idea what is causing the problem and how to solve this. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I am not Flutter pro but for iOS you need to have AppDelegate implements MessagingDelegate protocol (you could check iOS part of the Flutter project AppDelegate.m for it including implementation of the attemptToRegisterForNotifications and messaging functions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly configure properly your firebase for ios then
Add this in Info.plist

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

After that, add the following lines to the  `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method in the AppDelegate.m/AppDelegate.swift of your iOS project.

Read by yourself on here at the ios integration section follow the steps and it will work fine. [Link to package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)